# How to load server with python?

Tags: python, curl, flask, server, gunicorn

I have a WebApp on Flask+gunicorn+nginx. I need to send 200 requests from my other server **at the same time** to a WebApp , save the response and its speed. Also I need to send Json POST in this 200 requests.
How to do it right?
Use python script or CURL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after reading many articles, I went the next way:

[Using this lib](https://github.com/scribu/curio-http)

with next code:

```
import curio
import curio_http
import json
import requests

async def fetch_one(url):
    async with curio_http.ClientSession() as session:
        params =  {sample}
        response = await session.post(url, data=json.dumps(params))
        content = await response.text()
        return response, content


async def main():
    tasks = []
for x in range(300):
    task = await curio.spawn(fetch_one(sample))
    tasks.append(task)

for task in tasks:
    response, content = await task.join()
    #response = await task.join()

    print('GET %s' % response.url)
    print(content)
    print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   curio.run(main())
```

And it work fine!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use "Postman" for any kind of API testing. It is one the best tools available in the market for API testing , monitoring, documenting, and also sharing the results(as well as test scripts) **for free**.
If you don't want to use any other tool, then i suggest you to use a python script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But can Postmen send requests at the same time?